# bison recursion error with struct pointer

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have a simple struct called Polyn like this:

```
typedef struct Polyn {
  int sign;
  int coeff;
  int exp;
  struct Polyn *next;
} Polyn;
```

In my bison grammar for recursively building polynomials I only get the first and last element. I use these functions to add and make terms with the Polyn struct:

```
Polyn *addmonomial(Polyn *pol, Polyn *monom) {
    pol -> next = monom;
    return pol; 
}
```

So for a=1x2+2x+3, it only gives me 1x2+3.
The recursion will only build the first and last elements. I don't know whether to change the return value of the add function or how to change the grammar so the middle terms are included.
It seems like the problem is $1 in my last two recursive rules is always the first term and doesn't become the middle terms. I need to return the first term for my other grammar rules but also build the polynomial.

```
    |poln T_PLUS poln   { $$ = addmonomial($1, $3);}
    |poln T_MINUS poln  { Polyn *p2n = negate($3); $$ = addmonomial($1, p2n); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Polyn *addmonomial(Polyn *pol, Polyn *monom) {
    pol -> next = monom;
    return pol; 
}
```

This will override the existing value of `next` if `pol` already has a `next` value. So if `pol` represent the expression `1x2+2x` and `monom` represents `3`, then the `2x` part will be overridden by `1`.

Comment: How do i change the grammar to make it work?

Comment: i need to return the first term after all the recursive calls, but i also need each next value to point to the next term going all the way to the last term

Comment: @sidthekid It's not about the grammar - the grammar is fine. You'll need to fix your `addmonomial` function.

Comment: how bro? if i return monom instead of pol, then it forgets the first term and all the middle terms. it sets the pointer correctly but only returns the last term. Do i make monom point to pol?

Comment: @sidthekid You can do that if the order doesn't matter (that is, if you don't care that `foo + bar` will come out as `bar + foo`) - as long as `monom` is indeed monomial, it's `next` pointer will be `NULL` and thus safe to overwrite. Or you could add `monom` to the actual end of `pol` by following the `next` pointer until it is `NULL` - just like appending to a singly linked list, which is essentially what this is.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your `addmonomial` function and instead use an `addpolynomial` function.  While you're at it, get rid of the `sign` field, it is redundant with the sign of the `coeff` field.  You might also want to make the `coeff` field a `double` rather than an `int`.

Your `addpolynomial` function should merge the two linked lists of terms, combining terms with the same exponent.  Probably easiest if you always keep them sorted in exponent order.